# FormatException was unhandled error on vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm new to Stack Overflow, but anyway I'm having problem regarding my code. When I try to run the program and click the Login function I am getting an error on this statement ... Adapter.Fill(Table) It says: FormatException was unhandled. An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Login_page
    Private Sub Login_page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.CenterToScreen()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim MysqlConnection As New MySqlConnection("host=127.0.0.1; user=root; database = storage_db")
        Dim Command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `login_access` where username = @username and password = @password", MysqlConnection)

        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxUsername.Text
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxPassword.Text

        Dim Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(Command)
        Dim Table As New DataTable()

        Adapter.Fill(Table)

        If Table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have added some information to my answer that may be useful to your understanding of the actual behaviour of your original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are wrong for a number of reasons:

```vb
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxUsername.Text
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxPassword.Text
```

Firstly, you're using `MySqlClient` for MySQL, not `SqlClient` for SQL Server.  That means that you need to use `MySqlDbType` and not `SqlDbType`.

Secondly and thirdly, you need to decide whether you're using `Add` or `AddWithValue` because, as it is, you're mixing and matching.  If you use `AddWithValue` then you don't specify the data type as it is inferred from the value:

```vb
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text)
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text)
```

That's generally discouraged though, because the inferred type is often not the type you want.  That means that you should use `Add`.  In that case, you should also specify the size of variable-length data types:

```vb
Command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxUsername.Text
Command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxPassword.Text
```

EDIT:

For the record, what was happening in your original code was basically this:

```vb
Dim p = Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar)

p.Value = TextBoxUsername.Text
```

So a parameter was being added with a value of `SqlDbType.VarChar`, which would have been interpreted as an `Integer` and the parameter data type inferred from that.  The `Value` of that parameter was then being set using a `String` that could not be converted to an `Integer`, thus the `FormatException` was thrown.